# Deriving formula for surface area of an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, area, ellipsoids

I am doing some research on ellipsoids. I am not sure where the formula for the surface area of a prolate ellipsoid comes from. Can anyone please help me with how to derive the formula. I have the formula below

[image: the formula]

Comment: Where comes form this formula? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Surface_area

Comment: @EmilioNovati It does not show how the formula is derived

Comment: For prolate (or oblate) ellipsoid, use surface of revolution.

Comment: @NgChungTak Is there a way you can explain to me how that works ? Thank you

Comment: see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)

Comment: @NgChungTak Is there a way the formula can be derived from the formula in the link below.  (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/QuadricSurfaces_files/eq0003MP.gif )

Comment: Your formula is approximation only, it's a bit empirical.  For the formula I mentioned in my comments below, please refer to the journal [**here**](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037704279200009X)

Comment: @NgChungTak Is it possible for you to explain the formula. Because I don't understand some things on the formula . Thank you

Comment: What's your background?  For the approximate formula you mentioned in your question, I haven't seen any literature about it.  While elliptic integrals are rarely taught in university undergraduate courses.  Basically, I self-studied elliptic integrals by reading plenty of books in university library.  I suggest you to consult your professor or instructor for further information.

Answer (score 7):

The method is very standard and appears in most calculus texts.

Let $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ be the ellipse such that $a>b$.

- For prolate spheroid, it rotates about the $x$-axis.

\begin{align*}
  y &= \frac{b}{a} \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \\
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= -\frac{bx}{a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \\
  ds &= \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2} \, dx \\
    &= \sqrt{1+\frac{b^2x^2}{a^2(a^2-x^2)}} \, dx \\
    &= a\frac{\sqrt{1-\left( 1-\frac{b^2}{a^2} \right) \frac{x^2}{a^2}}}
            {\sqrt{a^2-x^2}} \, dx \\
  S &= \int_{-a}^{a} 2\pi y \, ds \\
    &= 4b\pi \int_{0}^{a}
       \sqrt{1-\left( 1-\frac{b^2}{a^2} \right)\frac{x^2}{a^2}} \, dx \\
    &= 4b\pi
       \left[
         \frac{x}{2} \sqrt{1-\left( 1-\frac{b^2}{a^2} \right) \frac{x^2}{a^2}}+
         \frac{a^2}{2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \sin^{-1} \frac{x\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a^2}
       \right]_{0}^{a} \\
    &= 2\pi b
       \left( 
         b+\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}
       \right) \\
\end{align*}

- For oblate spheroid, it rotates about the $y$-axis.

\begin{align*}
  x &= \frac{a}{b} \sqrt{b^2-y^2} \\
  \frac{dx}{dy} &= -\frac{ay}{b\sqrt{b^2-y^2}} \\
  ds &= \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{dx}{dy} \right)^2} \, dy \\
    &= \sqrt{1+\frac{a^2y^2}{b^2(b^2-y^2)}} \, dy \\
    &= b\frac{\sqrt{1+\left( \frac{a^2}{b^2}-1 \right) \frac{y^2}{b^2}}}
            {\sqrt{b^2-y^2}} \, dy \\
  S &= \int_{-b}^{b} 2\pi x \, ds \\
    &= 4a\pi \int_{0}^{b}
       \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{a^2}{b^2}-1 \right)\frac{y^2}{b^2}} \, dy \\
    &= 4a\pi
       \left[
         \frac{y}{2} \sqrt{1+\left( \frac{a^2}{b^2}-1 \right) \frac{y^2}{b^2}}+
         \frac{b^2}{2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \sinh^{-1} \frac{y\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b^2}
       \right]_{0}^{b} \\
    &= 2\pi a
       \left( 
         a+\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \sinh^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b}
       \right) \\
\end{align*}

> The two cases are interchangeable by flipping the roles of $a$ and $b$ together with $\sinh iz=i\sin z$

Comment: [+1} Note that $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}=c$ (distance from center to focii) and even more, for the first case $c/a=e$ (eccentricity) giving simpler looking formulas.

Comment: Is there a connection with the formula given by the OP ?

Comment: $$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

where $a\ge b\ge c$.

$$S=2\pi \left[ c^{2}+\frac{bc^{2}}{\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}}}\, F\left( \cos^{-1} \frac{c}{a}, k
 \right)+b\sqrt{a^{2}-c^{2}}\, E\left( \cos^{-1} \frac{c}{a}, k \right) \right]$$

$$k=\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{\frac{b^{2}-c^{2}}{a^{2}-c^{2}}}$$

For prolate,  $$b=c\implies k=0$$

For oblate,  $$a=b\implies k=1$$

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: ... where $E$ and $F$ are "incomplete elliptic integrals"

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, of course.

Comment: I just added this information for people unaware of the meaning of E and F. Their meaning cannot be retrieved unless they have at least the keywords "elliptic integrals".

Comment: Here is a site where one can find the formula given by the OP (http://planetcalc.com/149/). It is an **approximate** formula with a **precise** value of $p$...

Comment: An interesting reference: (www.citr.auckland.ac.nz/researchreports/CITR-TR-165.pdf)

Comment: I do not have the reputation to comment on his answer, but there is a typo in at least one line of Ng Chung Tak's answer above: the term before the asinh() expression should be ${ b^2 \over 2 \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}$. As printed now, the numerator is "b" instead of "$b^2$". [converted to comment by a moderator]

Comment: @Rudi, Amended, thanks for your response.