# Find the centre of gravity of an elliptic arc.

Tags: calculus, centroid

Find, without using Pappus' theorem, the centre of gravity of an arc of an ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ which situated in the first quadrant.

[image]

Comment: By [Pappus' centroid theorem][1] the problem is equivalent to finding the surface area of half an ellipsoid, hence elliptic integrals cannot be avoided.


  [1]: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE write your mathematics using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

For $a>b$,

\begin{align*}
  (x,y) &= (a\sin t,b\cos t) \\[5pt]
  e &= \sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}} \\[5pt]
  ds &= \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t+b^2\sin^2 t} \, dt \\[5pt]
  &= a\sqrt{1-e^2\sin^2 t} \, dt \\[5pt]
  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ds &= aE(e) \\[5pt]
  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x \, ds &=
  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} a^2\sin t \sqrt{1-e^2\sin^2 t} \, dt \\[5pt]
  &= \frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{ab^2}{2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
     \sinh^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b} \\[5pt]
  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} y \, ds &=
  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} ab\cos t \sqrt{1-e^2\sin^2 t} \, dt \\[5pt]
  &= \frac{b^2}{2}+\frac{a^2b}{2\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
     \sin^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a} \\[5pt]
 \begin{pmatrix} \bar x \\ \bar y \end{pmatrix} &= \frac{1}{2E(e)}
 \begin{pmatrix} 
   a+\dfrac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \sinh^{-1} \dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{b} \\[3pt]
   \dfrac{b^2}{a}+\dfrac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} \sin^{-1} \dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a}
  \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Compare the results with surface areas of spheroids [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050158/deriving-formula-for-surface-area-of-an-ellipsoid/2051128#2051128), an implication of Pappus' centroid theorem.