# Proof of this integration shortcut: $\int_a^b \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}=\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I came across this as one of the shortcuts in my textbook without any proof.
When  $b\gt a$,

> $$\int\limits_a^b \dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}=\pi$$

---

**My attempt :**

I notice that the the denominator is $0$ at both the bounds. I thought of substituting $x=a+(b-a)t$ so that the integral becomes
$$\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}$$

This doesn't look simple, but I'm wondering if the answer can be seen using symmetry/geometry ?

Comment: It's better to reduce to the $(a,b)=(-1,1)$ case rather than the $(0,1)$ case.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe  [here](https://youtu.be/lsPjvTEPCyQ?t=209) is an example

Comment: @InterstellarProbe So much the worse for Wolfie!

Comment: Ohk.. mother wolfram is rarely wrong, I'll check.. I'm trying to use @LordSharktheUnknown idea, but I don't see any easy way to change bounds right away. I feel kinda stuck, Lord may I know the substitution ?

Comment: $\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}=\beta(\dfrac14,\dfrac14)=\pi$

Comment: maybe try the substitution $t=\cos \theta$ or $t=\sin\theta$? I haven't tried it but the denominator would simplify

Comment: @rsadhvika It was my bad! I missed the square root in the denominator when I entered it into Wolframalpha.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Other way is substitution $t=\sin^2\theta$ so
$$\int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t)}}=\int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{2} 2dt=\pi$$

Answer (score 7):

Let $m = \frac{b+a}{2}$ and $r = \frac{b-a}{2}$. Consider the circle

$$ (x - m)^2 + y^2 = r^2. $$

Part of this locus with $y \geq 0$ is given by $y = \sqrt{r^2 - (x-m)^2} = \sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}$ for $a \leq x \leq b$. By the implicit differentiation, this function satisfies $ 2(x - m) dx + 2ydy = 0 $ and hence

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x-m}{y}. $$

So the length of the upper-circular arc is

$$ \pi r = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \, dx = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{\frac{(x-m)^2 + y^2}{y^2}} \, dx = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{r}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}} \, dx. $$

Dividing both sides by $r$ gives the desired answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's called an Abel Integral ( at least in my language ). You can write that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)\left(b-x\right)}}=\frac{2}{a-b}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2}{a-b}\left(x-\frac{b+a}{2}\right)\right)^2}}$$

that goes into arcsinus

> $$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)\left(b-x\right)}}=\text{arcsin}\left(\frac{2}{b-a}\frac{b-a}{2}\right)+\text{arcsin}\left(\frac{2}{a-b}\frac{a-b}{2}\right)=2\text{arcsin}\left(1\right)=\pi$$

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
  \tan^2 \theta &= \frac{x-a}{b-x} \\
  2\tan \theta \sec^2 \theta \, d\theta &=
  \frac{b-a}{(b-x)^2} \, dx \\
  2\sqrt{\frac{x-a}{b-x}} \times \frac{(x-a)+(b-x)}{b-x} \, d\theta &=
  \frac{b-a}{(b-x)^2} \, dx \\
  2\, d\theta &= \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}} \\
  \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}} &=
  2\tan^{-1} \sqrt{\frac{x-a}{b-x}}
\end{align}

The singularity in *Wolfram Alpha* comes from the upper limit $b$.

> **Geometrical interpretation**
>
> Considering circular arc $(x,y)=(\sqrt{b-u},\sqrt{u-a})$
>
> \begin{align}
>   ds &= \frac{\sqrt{b-a} \, du}{2\sqrt{(u-a)(b-u)}} \\
>   \tan \theta &= \sqrt{\frac{u-a}{b-u}} \\
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     x \\ y
>   \end{pmatrix} &=
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     \sqrt{b-a} \cos \theta \\
>     \sqrt{b-a} \sin \theta
>   \end{pmatrix} \\
>   ds &= \sqrt{b-a} \, d\theta
> \end{align}

See also another integral [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834619/pedal-form-to-polar-form-of-an-ellipse/2834872#2834872).

Answer (score 4):

I was taught to use the substitution $x=a \sin^2 \theta+b \cos^2 \theta$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=2\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{b-x}} d(\sqrt{x-a}) \\
& =2\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{(b-a)-(\sqrt{x-a})^2}} d(\sqrt{x-a}) \\
& =2\left[\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-a}}{\sqrt{b-a}}\right)\right]_a^b \\
& =\pi
\end{aligned}
$$