# How to evaluate $\int_{U}^{\alpha} \frac{dE}{\sqrt{(\alpha-E)(E-U)}}$ with the constraint $E \leq U$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is the integral I am struggling with:
$$
\int_{U}^{\alpha} \frac{dE}{\sqrt{(\alpha-E)(E-U)}}
$$
The solution claims it is $\pi$. However using an integral calculator, the integral seems to be zero.

Comment: What do you mean by the constraints $E\leq U $? $E$ is the dummy variable in the integral, so this doesn't make sense. Maybe you mean $ U\leq \alpha$?

Comment: Intuitively, consider an upper semicircle $y=\sqrt{(\alpha-E)(E-U)}$ with diameter given by thw two points $(U,0)$ and $(\alpha,0)$. Then the infinitesimal arc length is easily computed as $$\mathrm{d}s=\frac{R}{y}\,\mathrm{d}E,$$ where $R=(\alpha-U)/2$ is the radius of the circle. This tells that your integral is equal to the circumference of the semicircle divided by its radius, which is precisely $\pi$.

Comment: Essentially the same question: [Can't solve integral of Landau Lifschitz Classical Mechanics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2506448/13130)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853673/686284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $U<\alpha$, we may define a new variable of integration $\theta$ through the equation $E=U+(\alpha-U)\sin^2\theta$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_{U}^{\alpha} \frac{dE}{\sqrt{(\alpha-E)(E-U)}}&=
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2(\alpha-U)\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta}{\sqrt{(\alpha-U)\cos^2\theta\,(\alpha-U)\sin^2\theta}} \\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta = \pi.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

> Some clarification:
>
>
> The correct domain should be $a \ge U$. Otherwise, we result in a negative area.
>
>
> How did the integral calculator arrive at $0$? The entire graph of the integrand is above the horizontal axis, = no negative area/sign.

> $$(\alpha - E)(E - U) = -\alpha U + (\alpha + U)E - E^2 \\
> \xrightarrow{\text{completeSquare}} \left(\dfrac{\alpha - U}{2}\right)^2 - \left(E - \dfrac{\alpha + U}{2}\right)^2$$

$$\therefore \int{\dfrac{dE}{\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\alpha - U}{2}\right)^2 - \left(E - \dfrac{\alpha + U}{2}\right)^2}}} 
\\ = -\arcsin{\left( \dfrac{2E - U - \alpha}{U - \alpha} \right)} + C, \quad \alpha \ge U
$$

Hence,

$$\int^{\alpha}_{U}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(\alpha - E)(E - U)}}} = \left. -\arcsin{\left( \dfrac{2E - U - \alpha}{U - \alpha} \right)} \right|_{U}^{\alpha} 
\\ = \left(-\arcsin{\left( \dfrac{2\alpha - U -\alpha}{U - \alpha} \right)} +\arcsin{\left( \dfrac{2U - U -\alpha}{U - \alpha} \right)}\right)
\\ = -\arcsin{(-1)} + \arcsin{(1)} 
\\ = \pi$$