# Is there a general formula for the eccentricity $e$ of ellipsoid?

Tags: solid-geometry, ellipsoids

For an ellipse of eccentricity $e$ the formulas are:

${x^2 \over a^2} + {y^2 \over b^2} = 1 \\ e = \sqrt {1-\left({b \over a} \right)^2}$

what about the "3D case"?

Comment: Looking at the cross-sections, there will be three different eccentricities. Are you hoping to have a single number represent the "3d eccentricity" of the ellipsoid? If so, what would it represent?

Comment: I don't know really, I'd like to know $e$ with respect to z-axis, if it's possible

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)#Quadrics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 3D analogue of eccentricity, in the sense that there isn't a single real parameter that uniquely characterizes the shape up to scale. An $n$-dimensional ellipsoid's shape can be characterized up to rotations and reflections by $n$ real parameters, the [lengths of its principal axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem). These generalize the [semimajor and semiminor axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes), and for an ellipsoid with equation

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \frac{x_i}{\sigma_i} \right)^2 = 1$$

are given by the denominators $\sigma_i$. More generally, for an ellipsoid with equation $x^T M x = 0$ where $x = \left[ \begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{array} \right]$ and $M$ is a [positive-definite symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix), the principal axes are the lines spanned by the [eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of $M$ and the lengths of the principal axes are the inverses of the corresponding eigenvalues.

An ellipsoid is characterized up to rotations, reflections, and scaling by the ratios $\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_j}$ among the lengths of its principal axes; it suffices to consider the $n-1$ ratios $\frac{\sigma_i}{\sigma_{i+1}}$, arranging the lengths in order $\sigma_1 \ge \sigma_2 \ge \dots \ge \sigma_n$. Only when $n = 2$ does this boil down to a single number.

Quadrics which are not ellipses also have principal axes although the corresponding eigenvalues may be negative or zero, so the corresponding "lengths" may be negative or infinite.

Answer (score 1):

**In the aspect of measure of the boundary**

Perimeter of an ellipse

\begin{align}
  1 &= \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} \tag{$a \ge b$} \\
  P &= 4aE(e_{ab}) \\
  e_{ab} &= \frac{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}{a} \\
\end{align}

Surface area of an ellipsoid

\begin{align}
  1 &= \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2} \tag{$a \ge b \ge c$} \\
  S &= 2\pi
  \left[
    c^2+\frac{bc^2}{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}F(\theta,k)+b\sqrt{a^2-c^2} E(\theta,k)
  \right] \\
  \theta &= \cos^{-1} \frac{c}{a} \\
  k &= \frac{a}{b} \sqrt{\frac{b^2-c^2}{a^2-c^2}} \\
  &= \frac{e_{bc}}{e_{ac}} \\
  k' &= \sqrt{1-k^2} \\
  &= \frac{c}{b} \sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2-c^2}} \\
  &= \frac{e_{ab}}{e_{ac}}
\end{align}

- For prolate spheroid

$$b=c \implies (k,k')=(0,1)$$

- For oblate spheroid

$$a=b \implies (k,k')=(1,0)$$

- $k$ or $k'$ is not quite well-defined for the case of sphere.

**In the aspect of confocal system**

Confocal conics

\begin{align}
  1 &= \frac{x^2}{a^2+s}+\frac{y^2}{b^2+s} \\
  e^2 &= \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+s}
\end{align}

Confocal quadrics

\begin{align}
  1 &= \frac{x^2}{a^2+s}+\frac{y^2}{b^2+s}+\frac{z^2}{c^2+s} \\
  \kappa^2 &= \frac{a^2-c^2}{a^2+s}
\end{align}

- For $s\to \infty$, $\kappa \to 0$ which close to a sphere.
- For $s\to -c$, $\kappa \to 1$ which shrinks to focal ellipse namely

$$0=z=\frac{x^2}{a^2-c^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2-c^2}-1$$

- This can not analogous to paraboloids.

See also another posts of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050158/deriving-formula-for-surface-area-of-an-ellipsoid) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19849/definition-of-an-ellipsoid-based-on-its-focal-points/1837886?).