# Finding the surface area of a general semi-ellipse rotated around the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, definite-integrals

This problem comes from my school's problem set, and right now we're on the cusp of finishing Calc 2 and starting Calc 3 in a few weeks.

For a given curve with $x = f(t)$, and $y = g(t)$, surface area$$S=\int_a^bg(t)\sqrt{(f'(t))^2 + g'(t)^2}dt$$

A semi-ellipse is given such that $$(x,y) = (a\cos(t), b\sin(t))$$ from $0\le t\le\pi$.

Thus, plugging everything in, I got the integral of

$$\int_a^bbsin(t)\sqrt{(-a\sin(t))^2 + (b\cos(t))^2}dt $$

Simplifying:$$\int_0^\pi b\sin(t)\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(t) + b^2\cos^2(t)}dt $$

How do I solve this though? I tried using an integral calculator and I was only told this is a special elliptical integral.

However, my school tells us that we are able to prove that the integral equals $$2\pi b\left[ b +\frac{a^2}{c}\arcsin\frac{c}{a}\right]$$

where $$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$

Can anyone help me solve this integral?

Comment: One approach: Write $a^2\sin^2 t + b^2\cos^2 t = a^2 + (b^2-a^2)\cos^2t$, then substitute $u=-\cos t$.

Comment: Please refer to my older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050158/deriving-formula-for-surface-area-of-an-ellipsoid/2051128#2051128).