# Find the area of the ellipsoid $(\frac{x}{a})^2 + (\frac{y}{a})^2 + (\frac{z}{b})^2 = 1$, using Surface Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to find the area of the ellipsoid $(\frac{x}{a})^2 + (\frac{y}{a})^2 + (\frac{z}{b})^2 = 1$, using Surface Integral. I tried to use the method that I saw in another post on Math stackexchange. I parametrize the equation by letting $x = asin(u)cos(v)$, $y = a sin(u)sin(v)$, and $z = cos(u)$. 
Then I have $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = a cos(v) cos(u)$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = a sin(v)cos(u)$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial u} = -sin(u)$. 
Then I let $$E = a^2cos^{2}(v)cos^2(u) + a^2 sin^2(v)cos^2(u) + sin^2(u)$$Then I have $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = -asin(u)sin(v)$, $\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = a sin(u) cos(v)$, $\frac{\partial z}{\partial v} = 0$. 
Then I have $$F = a^2sin^(u)sin^(v) + a^2 sin^2(u) cos^2(v)$$
Then I also have $$G = -a^2 sin(u)cos(u) sin(v)cos(v) + a^2 sin(v)cos(v)sin(u)cos(u) = 0$$Then $$E+F-G = a^2 cos^2(u) + sin^2 (u) + a^2 sin^2(u)  = a^2 + sin^2(u)$$Then the area is $$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2 + sin^2(u)} dvdu$$Then I'm stuck on how to calculate this integral, since my instructor hasn't talked anything about elliptic integral.

Comment: Re your last sentence: the [area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#Surface_area) of the general ellipsoid involves elliptic integrals anyway, so you won't be able to do without them.

Comment: Pls refer to paper of [*Leo R.M. Maas*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037704279200009X) and my older post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2050158/deriving-formula-for-surface-area-of-an-ellipsoid/2051128#2051128).

Comment: @NgChungTak Thank you for your help!!